# change blueimp form used to submit data

Tags: jquery, file, upload, blueimp

If you have a form that contains a blueimp file input element like:

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="avatar"/>
    <input id="fileupload1" type="file" name="files[]">

    <input type="hidden" name="car"/>   
    <input id="fileupload2" type="file" name="files[]"> 
</form>
```

and you autoUpload a file **all** fields get submitted to the server (prior to form submission)

What i was hoping is that I could specify a separate form that is used for the file uploads that only contains the necessary `

The reason for this is i've got a rather large form and I dont want to submit the form and all those values each time an image is dropped onto the form. I need the file upload button to stay where it is (inside the form) and dont want to do any css rankness to quasi-nest two `<form>` elements.

Is there a way to simply hook into the submit event so I could just post the data when submit is pressed ? ( i know there is a hook for the submit event but I want one that allows you to easily access the image data)

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can set the fields to upload along the file using the `add` callback, something like this.

JS:

```
$( '#fileupload1' ).fileupload({
    add : function ( e, data ) {
        data.formData = {
            yourParam : $( 'input[name="avatar"]' ).val()
        };
        data.submit();
    }
});
```

Note that you need to set the other configuration parameters for the `fileupload` plugin: `url`, `dataType` and so on.

This `add` callback will append the field `yourParam` to the multipart request sent to the server with the file, it will be triggered when a file is added to upload and will inmediatly sent the file upload request.